# Etherbase ID changed during sync

Tags: mist

Creating an account in Mist I received an Etherbase ID which I then used to deposit funds (from Poloniex). However after syncing the Etherbase ID had changed (?). I can use the initial ID to see the funds in etherchain.org however how do I retrieve my funds? Someone suggested using myetherwallet however I don't know which info to enter so I can access the funds and resend them. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The "ID" you are talking about - I'm assuming that is the Address? It looks like

`0x7cb57b5a97eabe94205c07890be4c1ad31e486a8` and you view it on etherchain like this https://etherchain.org/account/0x7cb57b5a97eabe94205c07890be4c1ad31e486a8?

Can you go into Mist and go to Accounts -> Backup -> Accounts and see if there is anything in the keystore directory?

Comment: Yes there is a text file. It has the public key (which I used to send ETH to from Poloniex). This public key shows my funds when entered into etherchain.org.There are other text strings as well. When I copy paste those into www.myetherwallet.com and decrypt them I only get to see empty wallets.

Comment: Try upoading the keystore file (the UTC--..... file) to MyEtherWallet and decrypting it that way. In Mist, you still don't see that account / balance?